# A relative clause for this sentence

Tags: relative-clauses

Consider this sentence:

> Most historians trace the beginning of the Internet to Sputnik, the first satellite ..........

1. orbited the earth successfully.
2. to successfully orbit the earth.

The correct answer is 2. But why not 1? and why one should use "to" here?

Comment: the first satellite to orbit the Earth successfully. Also, that internet thing is  wrong. It was developed by the US military.

Comment: #1 is wrong because *the first satellite orbited the earth successfully* is syntactically a complete *sentence* - though an unlikely one, since it would require a context where ***first*** was clearly distinguished from others (such as the second and third satellites, which by implication failed to achieve orbit anyway). But in your cited context, *the first satellite to successfully orbit the earth* is simply an optional additional clause "defining, providing further details about" the preceding noun ***Sputnik***.

Comment: Note that *the first one **to** do it* means the same as *the first one **that/which** did it.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see, you mean #1 lacks a "that/which" to be grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

A relative clause identifies or qualifies or describes a preceding noun. It is normally introduced by a relative pronoun or relative adverb. It contains a subject and a properly inflected verb. So the proper way to use a relative clause in your example is **Sputnik, the satellite that first orbited the earth.** (As was pointed out in a comment, "successfully" is redundant.) The relative pronoun "that" is the subject and "orbited" is the verb.

The second option is to use an appositional phrase with a "to infinitive."
Such a phrase is an abbreviated substitute for a particular form of relative clause. In your example, it is abbreviating **Sputnik, which was the first satellite to orbit the earth.** The subject of the clause is "which" and the verb is "was." If the subject and verb are dropped, we get an appositional phrase with the infinitive retained: **Sputnik, the first satellite to orbit the earth.**

Comment: So, the "to" is because of the "first" and the pattern is "to be the first to do something"

Comment: @Ahmed Yes, that is the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> The first one **to do it** *will win* a prize.
>
> The first one **to do it** *wins* a prize.
>
> The first one **to do it** *won* a prize.

The infinitive in general does not refer to an occurrence of the action in real time; rather it refers to the action abstractly, outside of time. You can see from the examples above that the main verb can be future or past or present. So, the infinitive clause (in bold) is subject-oriented, telling us something about the subject.

> Is there a mechanic in town who can repair a 1952 Ford?
>   --The man **to do it** is Bob. He knows a lot about old cars.

We can paraphrase this clause with a relative clause:

> The man **who can do it** is Bob.

or with a prepositional phrase:

> The man **for the job** is Bob.